Idea on accountable watermarks using MPC. Does it make sense?
Next, I describe an idea to leverage MPC together with digital watermarking techniques to fight piracy. Can you point out any possible design flaws you see?
Accountable Watermarks
Piracy is a big problem. An instance of this problem relates to pirating PDF newspapers or academic papers. These are downloaded (or bought) by a single person and then spread infinitely. A similar instance of the same problem regards revenge porn. Some image is shared with a designated receiver and then, again, spread indefinitely all over the internet with undesired consequences for the sender. Although we cannot physically block someone from spreading an image or a file, we can create mechanisms that keep them accountable for such action. This is the premise of accountable watermarks.
Watermarks
Watermarking refers to techniques that embed subtle, typically invisible markers into images or files. There also exist ways to embed specific messages inside the watermark, such as least significant bits (LSB) manipulation. The basic idea of accountable watermarks is to add a watermark to a file and embed some private information, such as a private key, of the designated receiver/buyer inside this watermark. Every time the designated receiver reshares the file, there is an increased risk that the file might come again into the hands of the creator, which will be able to detect the person responsible for the piracy. A similar idea is applied to fight football streaming piracy: the broadcaster embeds the subscriber's identifier in the streamed video so that the user who is illegally re-streaming the content can be easily identified and punished.

Problems
There are a few problems with such a proposed solution regarding who has access to which information. Typically, the watermarking algorithm should be only known by the creator; it, it is easy for everyone to reverse-engineer it and remove the watermark from the received file. Furthermore, the watermarking algorithm requires its runner (the file creator) to know the information to be added inside the watermark. But a private key is, by definition, private and should not be known by anyone other than its owner, in this case, the designated receiver. If we were to embed public information, such as a public key of the designated receiver, inside the watermark, a malicious creator can just embed any public key of their enemies and then claim that they are guilty of piracy.
Solution
MPC comes as a good solution to deal with computation, in which secrets come from different parties. In the proposed solution, the creator inputs the parameters of their watermarking algorithm and the file to be sent. On the other side, the designated receiver inputs their private key. The 2PC runs the watermarking algorithm, using as inputs the file, the parameters and the information (private key) to be embedded into the file. The output (file with accountable watermark) is reconstructed only by the designated receiver.

Whenever the creator comes across, or gets sent by someone, the watermarked file they can now extract the private key of the designated receiver and claim their guiltiness. This should work with a ZK proof of private key extraction from an accountable watermarked file.

This is an area where there is extensive prior work and literature. Look under the keywords "traitor tracing" (for when people re-broadcast content only intended for themselves) as well as watermarking. What you are proposing does not seem to me to be very different from the literature.
All these work under certain on the power of attackers and the exact scenario that is addressed, but under such assumptions the problem is well understood.
Software based countermeasures are not very robust, and there is the ever-present method of physical bypassing of such techniques [record the broadcast which is on a laptop on your mobile and broadcast from there in a different network session, for example]. There is also white-box and black-box watermarking, as possible keywords to explore.
Some references:
A. Barg, G.R. Blakely, and G.A. Kabatiansky. Digital finger printing codes: problem statements, constructions, identification of traitors. IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory, 49: 852-865, 2003.
Benny Pinkas. "Traitor Tracing". doi:10.1007/978-1-4419-5906-5_158. 2011.
Ryo Nishimaki; Daniel Wichs; Mark Zhandry. "Anonymous Traitor Tracing: How to Embed Arbitrary Information in a Key" Archived 2016-10-12 at the Wayback Machine. p. 1.
Dan Boneh; Mark Zhandry. "Multiparty Key Exchange, Efficient Traitor Tracing, and More from Indistinguishability Obfuscation". 2013. p. 5.
Michel Abdalla; Alexander W. Dent; John Malone-Lee; Gregory Neven; Duong Hieu Phan; and Nigel P. Smart. "Identity-Based Traitor Tracing". 2007.
Amos Fiat; Tamir Tassa. "Dynamic Traitor Tracing". doi:10.1007/s00145-001-0006-7. Journal of Cryptology. 2001. pp. 212–213.
Simon McNicol, Serdar Boztaş, Asha Rao. "Traitor tracing against powerful attacks using combinatorial designs". AAECC'06: Proceedings of the 16th international conference on Applied Algebra, Algebraic Algorithms and Error-Correcting Codes
Tamir Tassa. "Low Bandwidth Dynamic Traitor Tracing Schemes". Journal of Cryptology. 2005. pp. 167-183.
Xingwen Zhao, Fangguo Zhang. "Traitor Tracing against Public Collaboration". 2011. p. 2.
